# SQL Server: Calculate length before decimal places

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the length of a values in a numeric column. The values are randomly as

```
255.0125 , 28847.0125 etc
```

I need the length of values before the decimal places only. So far the first value it should be 3, for second value it should be 5.

What SQL function can be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using FLOOR function, add ABS as well if numbers can be negative:

```
SELECT LEN(FLOOR(9.99999))
SELECT LEN(FLOOR(ABS(-9.99999)))
```

This will fail

```
SELECT LEN(cast(-9.99999 as int))--Result 2
SELECT LEN(FLOOR(-9.99999))--Result 3
```

Comment: SELECT LEN(FLOOR(9.99999)) working perfectly for me. Thanks for the Quick help @ Deepanshu

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select len(cast(999999999.99999 as int))

select len(cast(28847.0125 as int))
```

Or

```
select len(cast('28847.0125' as decimal))
```

Or

```
select len(round('28847.0125', 0, 1))
```

Or

**EDIT 2** *suggestion by [deepanshu-kalra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2273122/deepanshu-kalra)*
:

```
SELECT LEN(FLOOR(9.99999))
```

Comment: Floor can be used as well. `SELECT LEN(FLOOR(9.99999))`. I would have preferred this.

Comment: yes,true.i'm adding this to my answer. @DeepanshuKalra

Answer (score 0):

Use ROUND() function,  which will convert decimal to int, then use LEN()

query will be

```
select LEN(ROUND('255.0125', 0))
```

ROUND() function systax :

```
ROUND(value,decimalPlace)
```

Comment: this will fail `SELECT LEN(ROUND('9.99999', 0))`